# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list - python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some code like this:

```
for x in self.fiturs:
    a = x[:1] + x[-5]
    uji.append(a)
```

and the data is:

```
A,1,7,8,7,9
B,1,1,1,2,3
C,2,34,5,1,2
```

I just want to get `index 0` and `index 3`. So the output I want is like this:

```
A,8
B,1
C,5
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What is `type(self.fiturs)`?

Comment: `x[:1]` is a list not a `str`.

Comment: If self.fiturs is a list then I'd recommend using `a = x[1] + str(x[-3])`

Comment: @SHRAIYSH: Why the `str()` call on the element that's *already* a string? And what if the OP wanted a list instead?

Comment: The question did not show any difference in A and 8. It's possible that both are strings. It is also possible that 8 is <int> and A is str. Hence the str(). If you want a list, use `x[:1].append(str(x[-3]))` `x[:1]` gives you a list, `append()` adds to it. `str(x[-3])` adds the string form of x[-3]. If you want to add <int> form of the same, use `x[:1].append(x[-3])` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`x[:1]` is a `list` and `x[-5]` is a `str` in your case.

If you want the index 0 and 3 you can do:

```
a = [x[0], x[3]]
```

Comment: Perhaps this should be `a = [x[0], x[3]]`

Comment: True, we edited/commented at the same time :)

Comment: Well done for answering before the question was put on hold!  A good answer since you correct both the immediate problem the OP faced and the next one.

Comment: The OP says they want index 0 & index 3, so why are you even mentioning index 1?

Comment: @PM2Ring: The author of this answer addressed the most pressing problem of the OP first, namely syntax error. The next most pressing problem was that of correct output.

Comment: @quamrana Agreed, which is why I've upvoted it. But there's a little room for improvement. ;)

Comment: OP has edited his question... I'll edit the answer.